# php round not working when I use float 7 / 100

Tags: php

My code is very simple, for example, my php version is 5.5.11, this is my sample code:

```
$result = round(($num / 100), 2); // 0.070000000001
$result = $num / 100; // 0.070000000001
```

I get the `$result` is `0.070000000001`, and if `$num = 3`, the `$result` is correct. And I used `var_dump($num)`, the type is the float. how can I fix it?

**edit**

I found the reason, but I'm not sure the detail. I use Codeigniter, and I load a library `PHPExcel`, this is third party lib, when I load it, and I will have this problem, but I'm not sure the reason detail.

Comment: it is connected with how float digits are stored in PC memory

Comment: its working fine , [See demo](https://eval.in/464315)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. The exact format can only be achieved with strings, use http://php.net/number_format

Comment: My code had a lot of logic, I can't show a lot of codes, and I want to know what reason will cause this problem.

Comment: then read my answer and go to see link in manual. There is large red box that explains it deeply.

Comment: @lighter: does this answer your question?

Comment: I founded the problem, cause I use Codeigniter, and I load `PHPExcel` package, and I didn't load this package, it's work. But I don't know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in comment it is connected with how floats are stored in memory

From manual:

> Never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp functions are available.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

I don't know what you want to do with this float variable but if you want to compare then you need some $epsilon

`if(abs($a-$b) < $epsilon)`

if you want to round then probably you should ignore last digit. number_format() seems like better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with floating numbers.

You can even try [`bccomp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php)

```
    $a = 1.2 * 3;
    if (bccomp($a, 3.6) === 0) {
        echo 'equal';
    } else {
        echo 'not equal';
    }

    //echoes equal

    echo "----------------------";
    $a = 1.2 * 3;
    if ($a == 3.6) {
        echo 'equal';
    } else {
        echo 'not equal';
    }

    //echoes not equal
```